# Leanest way to compute term frequency without using the counter class on a bag ADT

Tags: python, algorithm, multiset

I have some code that works well computing term frequency on a chosen list using the counter class import.

```
from collections import Counter

terms=['the', 'fox', 'the', 'quick', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']

tf = Counter(terms)

print(tf)
```

The existing code works great but I am wondering what would be the leanest way to achieve the same result strictly using a bag/multiset ADT without the help of the python counter class.

I have spent several days experimenting with code and looking on other forums without much success.

Comment: By "leanest" do you mean fastest, or with least code? Or something else?

Comment: in terms of the least amount of syntax. thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by multiset?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiset

Comment: How does that for the task at hand. A bunch of singleton multisets? A single multiset that you still must iterate to count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single dictionary comprehension:

```
terms=['the', 'fox', 'the', 'quick', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
new_terms = {term:terms.count(term) for term in terms}
```

Output:

```
{'lazy': 1, 'over': 1, 'fox': 2, 'dog': 1, 'quick': 1, 'the': 3, 'jumps': 1}
```

using the `multiset`:

```
import itertools
import multiset
final_data = [multiset.Multiset(list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(terms))]
```

Output:

```
[Multiset({'dog': 1}), Multiset({'fox': 2}), Multiset({'jumps': 1}), Multiset({'lazy': 1}), Multiset({'over': 1}), Multiset({'quick': 1}), Multiset({'the': 3})]
```

Comment: this is using dictionary tho right?, not a bag. multi set.

Comment: import multiset, Pycharm doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: @SyntaxKiller what specifically is the error message?

Comment: my apologies, it does now, took a little fit,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common `dict` and loop over the terms and update counts using `get` with a default value:

```
tf = {}
for t in terms:
    tf[t] = tf.get(t, 0) + 1
```